# Any downside to using the "and" operator vs the && operator?

Tags: c++, operators

Any pros/cons to using the "and" operator vs the && operator? I personally think "and" is only going to cause confusion (ironically).

If there aren't any differences, why does it exist? It seems silly and unnecessary.

Comment: Nope, no difference. Choose which one you want (but keep it consistent).

Comment: This is a matter of some debate and not a good fit for StackOverflow. See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/1103313/78845 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/1703979/78845 (personally, I like the iso646 spellings of these operators).

Comment: Have +1 for a geek ice breaker.

Comment: Well, it is not as bad as trigraphs ;)  You'd better `#include <ciso646>` if you want your code to be portable.

Comment: It really does make sense when your code says `if (a öö b)` to instead use `if (a or b)`. But if your ´||´ actually looks like it should (which it does if you are using a PC or something else produced in the last 20 or so years) - the problem originates in the 128-character sets used in for example Sweden, Norway or Germany, which "stole" the "unusual" characters of []\ and {}| to make ÄÅÖ and äåö respectively, and I think ^ is ü, but I can't remember exactly.

Comment: Visual studio won't understand `and` ...

Answer (score 22, accepted):

They're anachronisms - they were originally introduced to accomodate folks who didn't have "^" or "|" characters on their keyboards.

Furthermore, although "and" and "&&" are equivalent ... "and" and "&" are quite different.  Using "and" instead of "&&" is simply confusing on a number of different levels, for several different reasons.  Including giving the poor maintenance programmer a completely unnecessary "wtf?" experience.

I would *not* use them in any code.  And I've certainly never *seen* them used in any "live" code.

IMHO...

Here's a bit more on the topic, if you're interested:

- [The written versions of the logical operators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2376448/the-written-versions-of-the-logical-operators)
- http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ciso646/
- https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_alternative

Comment: Why would you *not* use them in any code?

Comment: Same reasonsing as me I should think. I've been doing C & C++ on and off for 15 years, and I didn't even know they existed. You don't need comprehension failures around something this basic, things are hard enough.

Comment: I don't understand why people always complain for the bitwise operator for this topic.
"and" and "&&" as different as "bitand" and "&"
What's up with that?
Don't understand this part of your answer, please enlighten me

Comment: I very much disagree with the mentality of not using something just because it is new and different. Not only would I use the `and` operator, I would actually prefer it over `&&` for more reasons than just readability. See my answer to a similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54185388/3964397

Answer (score 32):

It's the same operator. The difference is merely one of style. Consult your project documentation, or ask your boss, or your wife, or flip a coin.

Comment: I asked my wife, who just happens to be an english major.  She prefers "and".  I suppose that's as good a reason as any.

Comment: I asked my boss, who just happens to be a lawyer. She prefers "&&", because "and" is used by plebs.