# Why alternative keywords are not famous in place of in-built ascii operators?

Tags: c++, coding-style, operators, keyword

In the list of [C++ keywords](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword), there are alternatives for the operators, such as:

```
&&  and
&=  and_eq
&   bitand
|   bitor
~   compl
!   not
!=  not_eq
||  or
|=  or_eq
^   xor
^=  xor_eq
```

In fact I personally find:

```
if(not s.empty())
```

more intuitive than,

```
if(!s.empty())
```

In many scripting language such words are the only option.
Why are not they famous in C++ over the operators? Is there anything to do with coding style or is it just a matter of taste.

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1103313/is-anybody-using-the-named-boolean-operators

Comment: @stefaanv, thanks, my question is a duplicate then. Voting to close.

Comment: Python has `not`, but although it defines "magic" methods with names like `__xor__`, they're still called using normal operator syntax. What other scripting languages utilize words over operators?

Comment: @Yuushi, I know only about Python, just wondered that it might be somewhere else as well.