# and, or, not versus &&, ||, !

Tags: c++, logic, keyword

Yes, this is valid C++ :

```
if (false or (true and not false)) ...
```

[Among others](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C++#C.2B.2B_operator_synonyms) such as `bitand` and `xor`. In C, they used to be macros, but now they [are keywords](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iso646.h#C.2B.2B) ! You can even overload them ! Then why would someone ever teach or write something like :

```
if (false || (true && !(false))) ...
```

Why is **nobody** using them ?

Comment: "In C, they used to be macros" No, they were never macros "in C", although some individual C programs may have defined such macros. Adn this isn't a real question, it's opinionated and argumentative -- see the FAQ.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is anybody using the named boolean operators?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1103313/is-anybody-using-the-named-boolean-operators) [Which C++ logical operators do you use: and, or, not and the ilk or C style operators? why?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1103313/is-anybody-using-the-named-boolean-operators) ; see also [C++ alternative tokens?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/555505/c-alternative-tokens) [Is it possible to turn off support for “and” / “or” boolean operator usage in gcc?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1069352)

Comment: @Jim Balter: But in C, they _are_ macros, defined in `iso646.h`.

Comment: @phresnel I stand corrected. But then the claim that they used to be macros but are now keywords in *C* is false ... they are still macros in C.

Comment: @Jim Balter: That's true, my comment was to both, you and the OP. Unfortunately one can't [at]ify multiple users.

Comment: @phresnel I believe that the OP always gets notified.

Comment: True. But now _you_ did possibly not know that I meant both :D

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because they don't allow mixed C/C++ code without including additional header files, are less known to programmers, and it's not immediately clear whether `and` is the short-circuit or bitwise version.

Comment: Yeah, between `&` and `&&` it is much easier to guess which one is a bitwise operator than between `and` and `bitand`. It is unfortunate though that `not_eq` is a relation, while `or_eq` is a compound assignment operator, which ironically is bitwise.

Answer (score 2):

Why nobody? Some use them. Others think that symbols are more readable than words.

Answer (score 2):

Visual C++ does not support them.

Comment: Microsoft Visual C++ requires <ciso646> to be included in order to use these identifiers, adding another useless dependency to something that should be in the base language. (or shouldn't, but shouldn't sit somewhere in the middle)

Answer (score 1):

People just don't know about them(I didn't until now).