# C++ writing 'or' instead of ||

Tags: c++, syntax

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C++ alternative tokens?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/555505/c-alternative-tokens)

I'm working on an assignment in C++ with a friend of mine, and we've been doing lots of the coding on his computer/environment (a Macbook Pro with Eclipse). In some of the code he has written conditions using `and` and `or` rather than `&&` and `||`. The code compiles just fine on his computer, but when I try and compile it on my computer at home (a PC with Visual Studio 2010) I get compiler errors and am forced to switch them. My friend also attests that this syntax has worked using emacs/g++ in a Linux environment.

I had never seen this type of thing before. Is this used widely or supported by most compilers?

Comment: See also: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/34h23df8.aspx under "ISO646.H Not Enabled"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are a handful of "alternative representations":  `and`, `and_eq`, `bitand`, `bitor`, `compl`, `not`, `not_eq`, `or`, `or_eq`, `xor`, and `xor_eq`.  They are a standard language feature of C++.

Visual C++ only supports these as keywords if you compile with the `/Za` (standards conformance mode) flag.

Answer (score 6):

[`#include <iso646.h>`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iso646.h)

Comment: Being C++, shouldn't this be `<ciso646>`? And isn't that file supposed to be empty?

Comment: No, being C++ you need not include anything. These are keywords. Blame your compiler if it doesn't work.

Comment: @Martinho: `ciso646` is just an alias for `iso646.h`, since there aren't any names to move into the std namespace.  And either one is a no-op in C++ mode with any conforming compiler.  Since adding `#include <iso646.h>` will not harm any conformation compiler, and will make Visual C++ work, so why not?

Answer (score 3):

They're called [operator synonyms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B#C.2B.2B_operator_synonyms), and they're apparently part of the standard, but I'm not sure how widely supported they are.

Answer (score 1):

Could you add `define`s to the top to get around it?

```
#define and &&
#define or ||
```

Comment: Strictly speaking, no, since `and` and `or` are keywords and cannot be defined as macros.

Comment: @JamesMcNellis: Strictly speaking they are alternative tokens, not keywords. You still can do this because technically `#define and &&` is just another way to spell `#define && &&` which is not legal.

Comment: @Charles:  Oh.  Well, it is very misleading that they are listed in the subclause named "Keywords."  You're right, of course.

Answer (score -1):

It is either caused by a compiler extension or a `#define` somewhere else in the source code, possibly from `iso646.h` `define`ing `or` to be `||` and `and` to be `&&`. You might also see something like using `not` in place of `!` as well.

If it is a compiler extension and you want to avoid having to go through and change all the `or` and `and` to `||` and `&&`, simply add some `#define`s of your own at the top:

```
#define or ||
#define and &&
```

Comment: Would it make more sense then to always just use the standard version? Seems like that is the smartest course of action.

Comment: No, `and` / `or` / `eq` / `bitand` / etc. are keywords in C++. They're synonyms for the operators.

Comment: @Chris can you really count something that has to be `define`d as a keyword?

Comment: @Seth - They don't have to be `#define`d. They're keywords. Visual C++ doesn't follow the standards.

Comment: @Seth: According to the C++ standard, they are reserved words, and cannot be defined as macros.  In Visual C++, like C, they're enabled by `iso646.h`.  But if Visual C++ uses macros to implement them, that's an implementation detail.  It doesn't make it legal for the programmer to `#undef` or redefine them (unfortunately, since I once wanted to `#undef` them).