# "Exploring C++ book" compiler setup

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, standard-library

I just got this book "Exploring C++" and I'm on my first lesson. I've been doing C# for a couple years as a hobby so i though why not give C++ a try.

In the book it says i need to setup my compiler to use standard C++. I am using visual studio 2010 so i did. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235629.aspx

but when i go to compile the code it all works fine except for one if statement.

i have triple checked just as instructed so it must be something with the tools.

specifically

```
if (not in) // this line here
{
    std::perror(argv[1]);
    return EXIT_FAILURE;

}
```

The full sample

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <ostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

void read(std::istream& in, std::vector<std::string>& text)
{
    std::string line;
    while (std::getline(in, line))
        text.push_back(line);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::vector<std::string> text;

    if (argc <2)
        read(std::cin, text);
    else 
    {
        std::ifstream in(argv[1]);
        if (not in)
        {
            std::perror(argv[1]);
            return EXIT_FAILURE;

        }
        read(in,text);
    }

    std::sort(text.begin(), text.end());

    std::copy(text.begin(), text.end(),
        std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, "\n"));
}
```

I would really like to continue with this book so any help is greatly appreciated.

And I apologize if this is awfully noobish of me.

Comment: according to this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/555505/c-alternative-tokens you should use /Za switch to disable the extension.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`not` is an "alternative token" for the boolean operator `!`.

Perhaps your compiler doesn't support it.

Try this instead:

```
if (!in)
```

---

Indeed, [here's *exactly* the same issue on another site](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vclanguage/thread/03198dd1-4741-48cb-acc8-ccacec075f50/).

> VC compiler doesn't by default recognize alternative tokens (they are exceedingly rare nowadays), but I believe this support may be turned on with a compiler switch.

In fact, Visual Studio requires that you `#include <ciso646>` to get support for alternative tokens, even though the C++ Standard states that this should have no effect<sup>1</sup>. Naughty Visual Studio!

> In any case, you might want to find a better, more modern textbook.

I recommend [these resources](http://jcatki.no-ip.org/fncpp/Resources).

---

> <sup>1</sup> `[n3290: footnote 176]:` In particular, including the standard header `<iso646.h>` or `<ciso646>` has no effect.

Comment: Thank you, that solved my not problem. Now i have two errors that do not point to any code. Seems strange that a book published in 2008 wouldn't mention that. Anyway, id rather have something more up to date so Im going to check out those resources you linked. Thanks again for those.

Comment: In Visual Studio you can also use the /Za option to disable Microsoft extensions. Interestingly, one of their _extensions_ is to disable alternative tokens.

Comment: @Seth: And it's deprecated. I'm sure you meant `<ciso646>`.

Comment: Error 1 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _WinMain@16 referenced in function ___tmainCRTStartup d:\CPPTut\Tutorial\Tutorial\MSVCRTD.lib(crtexew.obj) Tutorial

Comment: Error 2 error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals d:\CPPTut\Tutorial\Debug\Tutorial.exe 1 1 Tutorial

Comment: @leetbit: Iterative debugging discussion is not a good fit for this site's Q&A format. Perhaps you'd be happier in [one of the chatrooms](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/)?

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal: ah.. no rep. I am gonna use one of your resources now. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: @Tom no, I actually did mean `<iso646.h>` because it does work, but like you said (and like I just found out), it's deprecated also, so to everyone who reads this, use `ciso646`.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
if (!in)
```

instead of

```
if (not in)
```

as this is the code style that most C++ programmers are used to.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use `/za`. The thing is that it causes numerous compiler bugs when switched on and more important compiler problems like SFINAE aren't resolved anyway, and some headers like Windows headers won't compile.

Technically, the `not` keyword is used for the `!` operator. You may find that MSVC doesn't support it, so just use `!` directly.

Comment: OK, it is. (`[n3290: C.3.2.3/1]`). `2.12` is a little more ambiguous about it, but there we go.

Comment: It's actually not so bad. We separate Windows-specific and portable code, and can use `/Za` for the portable parts. That `windows.h` won't compile with `/Za` is a feature for us; it prevents accidents.