# What is the name for using "or" instead of || in c++?

Tags: c++

I ran into an interesting line of code today. I did not know it was legal to use the word "or". I thought there was only ||. 
What is this called and where can I read more about it?
Thanks

```
if (V_discount == "y" or "Y" or "Yes" or "yes")
           {
               cout << "Your discount is: ";
}
```

edit: It turns out the if statement doesn't do much. I put a cout<<"hi"; in the brackets, and it executes regardless of what V_discount has in it.

I thought it was called something because netbeans is highlighting "or" in blue.

2nd edit:

```
v == "y" || "Y"
```

is not the same as

```
v == "y" || v == "Y"
```

Only the latter functions "as intended". "As intended" being checking whether v is the string "y" or v is the string "Y".

Comment: You also can't compare strings like that. :) (unless it's of type `string`)

Comment: Why do you think it's called something in particular?

Comment: @Mysticial: It wouldn't work for std::string either. The `==` part would, but the actual `or`s are pure nonsense. Or at least, not what he expects them to be.

Comment: If he isn't including iso646.h its possible its some horrible macro that allows it to work. And if he is referring to the synonym for ||, as far as I know they're just called operator synonyms.

Comment: @NicolBolas That's why I said "also" since it's a separate issue.

Comment: Did you also know that C++ provides functor objects for every logical operator (and other non-logical operators) in the language? (They are called `logical_or`, `logical_and`, `logical_not`, etc)

Comment: Answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/555505/c-alternative-tokens

Comment: Just as a note, GCC supports these keywords out of the box, as synonyms to "||" and "&&", etc

Comment: @myrkos: It's actually demanded by the standard.

Comment: MSVC doesn't support them without a header IIRC, and I assume MSVC implements them as macros in that header.

Comment: @bames53: MSVC (I just tried the 2010 Express version) does support the standard alternative tokens (`and`, `or`, `<%`, `%>` -- but only if you enable the `/Za` option, which the GUI describes as "Disable Language Extensions".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's called an "alternative token", documented in section 2.6 [lex.digraph] of the current ISO C++ standard, and in section 2.5 of the 1998 ISO C++ standard.  (This is the same section that defines "digraphs", such as `<%` for `{` and `%:` for `#`.)

But the code you've shown uses it incorrectly.

First, if `x` were an `int`, then you'd probably want this:

```
if (x == 10 or x == 20 or x == 30)
```

rather than this:

```
if (x == 10 or 20 or 30)
```

The latter is actually legal, but it means something quite different.

And comparing strings for equality is not straightforward.  If `V_discount` is a `char*` or `char[]`, then comparing `V_discount == "yes"` compares pointer values, not the contents of the strings, and they'll certainly compare unequal.  If `V_discount` is a `std::string`, then I think it will work -- but you still have to compare it to each of the literals individually.  Otherwise, as Tony Delroy's answer says, it compiles but does something entirely unexpected involving implicit conversions to `bool`.

Comment: I think you theoretically could overload `||` with a custom class to make `x == 10 or 20 or 30` "work" but I wouldn't advise it.

Comment: @Chris: [Guess what I wrote some time ago](http://ideone.com/kVngH). :> However, alas, it won't short-circuit anymore. :(

Comment: @Xeo: in the same vein, you now have `std::all_of`, `std::any_of` and `std::none_of`. They can easily be wrapped into more interesting interfaces (shifting to ranges over iterators) to yield `if (any_of({"y", "Y", "yes", "Yes"}, V_discount))`. I quite found unfortunate that the Standard Library would only offer predicate versions, but wrapped you can add the regular value comparison easily enough.

Answer (score 2):

*The C++ Programming Language* (page 829) just refers to them as "keywords", not giving them any special name. The C++11 standard (section 2.6) calls them "alternative token representations", but also includes e.g. `<%` (for `{`) under that name (which, I suppose, explains why it can't just call them "keywords"); I don't know if earlier standards used the same terminology.

Wikipedia [calls them "operator synonyms"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C++#C.2B.2B_operator_synonyms), but that name doesn't seem to be in currency elsewhere.

Answer (score 2):

> I ran into an interesting line of code today. I did not know it was legal to use the word "or". I thought there was only ||. What is this called and where can I read more about it? Thanks

It's legal.  Sadly, the Microsoft Visual C++ compiler doesn't support it (at least by default - maybe there's an obscure command line switch or something).  Because of the lack of portability, even people who know about them (`or`, `and`, `xor`) and prefer them stylistically may decide not to use them.

> if (V_discount == "y" or "Y" or "Yes" or "yes")            {                cout << "Your discount is: "; }

"y" "Y" "Yes" and "yes" are all string literals - basically compiler-generated character arrays of the quoted text and a NUL terminator suffix (i.e. the "C" string representation, for ASCII text the ASCIIZ name is often used - Z referencing the zero/NUL value of the final byte).  When these values are combined in an logical `or` expression, they first decay to pointers to the first character, then the pointers are quietly converted to `bool` values that can be ORed together.  The pointers will all be non-0 values addressing the respective character buffers, and when promoting integral values to `bool` C++ considers any non-0 value to be `true` (and 0 `false`).  So, the entire expression is equivalent to `(V_discount == "y") or true or true or true`.  Anything `or true` is `true`, so the `if` statement always executes the following statement block, as you found...

> edit: It turns out the if statement doesn't do much. I put a cout<<"hi"; in the brackets, and it executes regardless of what V_discount has in it.
>
> I thought it was called something because netbeans is highlighting "or" in blue.

Editors often have a list of "keywords" significant in the languages they support, typically with various sub-categories corresponding to on-screen (or -printer) style, but that doesn't necessarily correspond to the language Standard's classifications.  In C++, `or` is just a functionally-identifical alternative to `||`, and both are called "or" or - more precisely and to differentiate them from the bitwise version - "logical or".

> 2nd edit:

```
v == "y" || "Y"  is not the same as
v == "y" || v == "Y"
```

> Only the latter functions "as intended". "As intended" being checking whether v is the string "y" or v is the string "Y".

Generally true.  If `v` is a user-defined type and the `||` operator is overloaded (replaced) by the programmer, it can actually operate "as intended", but we C++ programmers are so used to typing the second form (which works for inbuilt and Standard library value-semantic types like int and `std::string`) that we find having the `v == "y" || "Y"` "work" as per `v == "y" || v == "Y"` incredibly confusing, and invariable the C++ literature recommends against changing the weird but developer-familiar way of interpreting the former statement.

Note that given `char v[some-number];` and candidate text in `v`, the above comparison would need to do the written `strcmp(v, "y") or strcmp(v == "Y")`.

Comment: Didn't you mean "It's legal, sadly.  The Microsoft..."?

Comment: @Ben: Not at all. ;-P.  I know a lot of C++ developers shun the very thought of abandoning the C-style `||`, `&&` and `^` tokens, but having used `and`, `or` and `xor` in other languages it can "read" nicely too... I'm indifferent, but certainly don't think a compiler vendor has any business deliberately not implementing (and enabling by default) such a trivially-achievable aspect of the Standard....

Comment: Shall we also allow `begin` and `end` instead of `{}`.  It works for other languages...  I'm not impressed by the ability to make C++ feel syntactically more like Basic, when the underlying semantics are so totally different.  BTW, in Basic and VHDL, `Or` is equivalent to C's `|`, not `||`.  Perl has both `||` and `or` with different precedence.  So this actually makes matters worse.

Comment: @Ben: I'm sure the committee discussed it thoroughly, and imagine the driver must have been the same as for trigraphs (character sets and I/O devices lacking support for the usual symbols).  An ugly reality all up.  Regardless, a compiler vendor has no business second guessing the Standard if they're shipping what they call a "C++" compiler.