# Written version of logical operators: Not supported in Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-studio-2013, keyword

In answers to [The written versions of the logical operators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2376448/the-written-versions-of-the-logical-operators), it is indicated that the keywords `and`, `or`, and `not` are, in fact, keywords that are defined as part of the C++ language (but without specifically stating C++11).

In Visual Studio 2013, I am attempting to build pre-existing code (known to build on Linux) which uses the `or` keyword (`if (A_ or B_) {...}`, where `A_` and `B_` are properly defined), and the following compiler error is generated:

> error C2065: 'or' : undeclared identifier

From [Microsoft's (apparently) official list of C++ keywords](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2e6a4at9.aspx) for Visual Studio 2013, `or` is not listed.

I would like confirmation that the `and`, `or`, and `not` keywords are not supported in Visual Studio 2013.

(The alternative is that I am missing either an `#include` file, or a required compiler setting.)

Comment: You need to include a header IIRC in MSVC2013 (== nonstandard) `iso646.h`, [and_eq @ MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1s7s448s.aspx)

Comment: Probably a duplicate question. Try disabling language extensions: http://stackoverflow.com/a/555524/420683

Comment: A bit of history: They've been introduced because `&` and `!` etc were fancy characters back then, not supported or forbidden for certain architectures, or even reused for localized characters in a 7-bit pseudo-ASCII character set. A more readable alternative to trigraphs (source: D&E, pp.159-160)

Comment: Be aware that if you do disable language extensions using `/Za` then there's a good chance you won't be able to include most (probably all) of the Windows API headers.

Comment: @dyp: Yes, but alternative tokens don't entirely replace trigraphs, since they're not replaced in string and character literals.