# Error: operand types are incompatible ("int" and "const char*") c++

Tags: c++

This is my code, the error is as displayed in the title. And in the compiler:

```
1>c:\users\ägaren\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\yt tutorial hd\yt tutorial hd\main.cpp(26): error C2446: '==' : no conversion from 'const char *' to 'int'
```

And:

```
1>c:\users\ägaren\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\yt tutorial   hd\yt tutorial hd\main.cpp(26): error C2040: '==' : 'int' differs in levels of       indirection from 'const char [4]'
```

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <string> 
using namespace std;


int main()
{
   int gold=600, level=1, exp, damage=10, health=100, mana=100, manaLevel=1;          // Main Vars      
   string name;
   cout << "Hello, what is your name?: ";
   cin >> name; 
   cout << "Welcome " << name << " to the field of war,\nYou will stumble upon many other brave warriors.\nTake care and good luck.\n";
   Sleep(500);

   cout << "You're first task is to eliminate the Orc leader.\n";
   int orc=15, troll=25, mage=50; // Enemy Vars
   int healthpotion=25, manaPotion=25; // Potions vars
   int ifAttack; // if the user chooses to attack or not.
   Sleep(500);
   cout << "Tossan: " << name << " I hereby order you to attack the orc, he is up north.\nThis message will delete in 2.5 seconds.";
   Sleep(2500);
   system("cls"); // 1st screen clear.
   cout << "After heading north you stumble upon the Orc, will you attack him? [y/n]\n";
   cin >> ifAttack;
   if (ifAttack == "yes")

}
```

the if (ifAttack == "yes")
is what is giving me the erros, == is underlined but i cant find how to fix it. c++

Comment: `ifAttack` is meant to be the answer to a yes-or-no question. Why did you define it as an `int`, and what do you expect the user to enter at the `[y/n]` prompt? Even if your code worked, you'd reject a response of `y` because it doesn't match `"yes"`.

Comment: ah yes, ifAttack is suppose to be a string right?
I remade the code abit at the end it was if (ifAttack == "y")
but i changed it to clarify the code abit.
Thx :)

Comment: Change `int ifAttack;` to `string ifAttack;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare `ifAttack` not as an `int` but like the:

```
string ifAttack;
```

You can then read it in just as you were doing with: `cin >> ifAttack;`

But since you're only really concerned with whether the user entered a 'y' for the first character change your `if` statement to:

```
if(ifAttack.front() == 'y' || ifAttack.front() == 'Y')
```

**EDIT:**

Filtering user input can be a difficult task. But if you decide that you want to take that on you can compare the *whole* `string` rather than just the first character. That way "yellow elephant" does not mean "yes":

```
if(_stricmp(ifAttack.c_str(), "yes") || _stricmp(ifAttack.c_str(), "y"))
```

`_stricmp` is a Microsoft only function: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k59z8dwe.aspx
`strcasecmp` is the Linux equivalent: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strcasecmp.html

I would suggest you save filtering your input till the end of your project. It can be tedious. For example the string comparisons above don't match "YES!".

Comment: I mean as in, erm it will run the code under even if only 1 is true?

Comment: @Yamiez No. `||` means `or`. I'm using it to check case. Remember that 'y' is not the same character as 'Y'. So I'm going to check if the user entered either one in the `if`statement.

Comment: @JonathanMee That's awesome. Now the user can enter "yellow elephant" and still have their answer taken as a yes.

Comment: @Yamiez The `else if` won't help you here. If the user entered "yello elephant" it would meet the `if` condition and never make it to the `else if`. I've added an edit to help you match the entire `string` rather than just the first letter. Also if `||` is confusing to you, you might check out this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/555505/c-alternative-tokens#comment43978668_555524

Comment: @JonathanMee but it is working for me now, i've added in if else if and else. And if i type yellow elephant i get the cout i made in else :)

Comment: @Yamiez Sounds like this is the solution? If so I'd appreciate an accept. If you had to do a bunch of work past what I have mentioned here, I'd recommend that you post your own answer explaining what you did for posterity.

Comment: @JonathanMee im a bit of a noob on this website, what do you mean by "an accept" :P
I already knew how to make yellow elephant or any other sort of words not  register as "yes" or "no". 
It was just a big newbie mistake by me, not using a string! :D

Comment: @Yamiez Just click the empty check box to the left of this answer. That helps flag anyone who stumbles on your answer with a similar problem that this answer fixed your issue.

Comment: [_"Filtering user input can be a difficult task. But in our future, Microsoft and I fight to make it safe. I am Jonathan Mee, author of this answer, and these are my suggestions."_](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jPYvwPN1eU8)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Don't know how much sarcasm that was laced with but it gave me a good laugh when I clicked on the link :J

Comment: @JonathanMee: No sarcasm, only playfulness. That first sentence just reminded me of it and I couldn't help myself.

Comment: @JonathanMee No sorry, didn't even notice I unccepted?