# Why does Clang not allow "and" as function name?

Tags: c++, clang, clangpowertools

I'm developing a program for some time now, using Visual Studio 2017. Lately I installed the Clang Power Tool extension in order to check the quality of my code.
Part of my program consists in emulating the opcodes of a cpu. I created a stripped down example below.

The following example works fine :

```
class C{};

inline void andi(C& s);

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello, world!\n";
}
```

This one does not :

```
class C{};

inline void and(C& s);

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello, world!\n";
}
```

I'm getting these errors on Clang 3.8.0 (I'm using version 9.0.1 on my program, and errors are similar) :

```
source_file.cpp:9:18: error: expected ')'
inline void and(C& s);
                 ^
source_file.cpp:9:16: note: to match this '('
inline void and(C& s);
               ^
source_file.cpp:9:13: error: cannot form a reference to 'void'
inline void and(C& s);
            ^
source_file.cpp:9:1: error: 'inline' can only appear on functions
inline void and(C& s);
```

Looks like that functions named after binary operations (like and, not, or and xor) trigger a wrong behaviour in the compiler.
No errors are shown using the Visual Studio compiler, and the program works as expected.

Is there something I can do to prevent this from happening ? Or is this a bug in Clang ?
Adding NOLINT to the line doesn't help as it's the compiler which raises the error ...

You can test the case here : https://rextester.com/TXU19618

Thanks !

Comment: `and` is synonym to `&&`

Comment: It's not a bug in Clang; it's a bug in Visual Studio (unless you've told it to compile against an old C++ standard that pre-dates the `and` keyword).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`and` is a reserved keyword in C++ which means it cannot be used for a function name. This is standard C++ behavior, not an error.

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword

Comment: However, the Visual Studio native MSVC compiler [requires the `/Za` option](https://stackoverflow.com/a/555524/10871073) in order to use these 'alternate' keywords.

Comment: Looks like Visual Studio compiler is too lax then ;) Thanks for the heads up, I'll do the changes. @Adrian Mole : looks like I don't have this compiler option enabled ;)